# Flask - HTTP methods post and get gives error when positions exchanged

Tags: http, flask, methods

Today I was playing around with my Flask project and found that when I change:

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

to

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["POST", "GET"])
```

that is, when I change the order of `“POST”` and `”GET”`, it produces some error, since I have solved the typo bug. But, my question today is how the order of `”POST”` and `”GET”` really matters, because I am not able to find any answers online.

Comment: What specific error message were you getting?

Comment: Just tried this locally with a hello world project and I cannot replicate. It works fine. Must have been something else you changed that fixed the error.

Comment: what i implemented inside search was a database query to return search results if method was POST and a index page if method was GET. @TimThompson